# WSS/BPOS Is there an easy way to copy site-collections?

Tags: wss-3.0, site-collection, sharepoint-online

Quite often I use site collections per calender year. They contain team sites with task lists and datawebsites(multipage meetingsites). When you copy the individual websites they do exactly what I want, keep the tasks and empty the datasites. Both are in the same site collection. So I thought if I can copy the site collection than it will save a lot of time. Any ideas, to do it the easy way?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to create a site collection from a template, that template needs to be available at farm level (you should see it as an option in the create site collection page under app management). Saving a site as a template will save it at the site collection level. This article describes how to make your template a site collection template:

http://blog.gavin-adams.com/2007/07/03/creating-site-collection-templates/

Answer (score 0):

If you save the root of the site collection as a template (STP file) I think it saves the subsites (your meeting workspaces).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I thought I'd give it a try and have tested it in my WSS. But this is not giving me the result I'm looking for for more reasons: - A site template can be created, but when it is re used it behaves as a site and not as a site collection, it looses all sub sites. - It cannot be used as a template for a site collection, because a site collection is not catered for custom sites,it only has collaboration and meeting site templates. I wished it was because than it might work. So sorry, but I have to go deeper, do you have a better alternative, or someoneelse?

Comment: I did save the root of the site collection with site actions>site settings>save as a template.
But if I create the new site from this template, all subsites have disappeared.
This is exactly the reason why I have raised this question. because I would realy like to have a solution that simple as you suggest. I don't want to go all the way in the application management in WSS, it is the intention to have such an option available for the site admin